# Could not resolve package that is imported in node_module dependency in Nuxt 3 (apollo client)

Tags: import, node-modules, apollo-client, nuxt3

I'v added **Apollo client** to Nuxt 3 **(With Vite)** project but on `yarn dev` it fails and throws

✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "react"

```
node_modules/@apollo/client/react/hooks/useApolloClient.js:2:27:
  2 │ import { useContext } from 'react';
    ╵                            ~~~~~~~
```

*You can mark the path "react" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this
error.*

✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "react"

```
node_modules/@apollo/client/react/hooks/useMutation.js:2:57:
  2 │ import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
    ╵                                                          ~~~~~~~
```

*You can mark the path "react" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this
error.*

Q: So how can I mark path "react" as external ? Or make it to work, couldn't find any tutorials how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in `@apollo/client` import,
make sure that all imports are from `@apollo/client/core`
Example

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloLink,
  HttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
  PureQueryOptions
} from "@apollo/client/core";
```

**[!]Not:** `.. from "@apollo/client";`